# How to store data on the ethereum using decentralized application

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I am trying to build a Decentralized application on ethereum using the solidity language.

How can i use Ethereum as database?

I mean i just want store image file on Ethereum using decentralized application.

Is that possible?

And how will it be in solidity?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the guidelines on how to ask a good question and update yours accordingly. As it is currently written, it may be closed as a "too broad" question.

Answer (score 1):

you can use IPFS (checkout here : https://ipfs.io) to store data like images on the chain. Also you can checkout BigchainDB, put I assume that the first will be more suitable for your case

Answer (score 0):

Storing the data on Blockchain is a costly affair.It can cost you approx.5 dollars even for the smallest kb(e.g.1 kb),calculated upon the basis of gas price.We normally store hashes of the data.
You can use 2 techniques depends upon your problem:

1. Storing hashes of data.
2. Combination of data and hashes.
   We can use IPFS (https://ipfs.io/) for storing hashes to the blockchain and we can use GPG encryption to make it secure.